# C++ Palindrome algorithm - No match for 'operator<'

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, palindrome

My below C++ Palindrome agorithm implementation results in the following error:

> No match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream< char >' and '< unresolved overloaded function type >')

The error happens on the ending `else` line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Write a number to check if its palindrome" << endl;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    int z = a;
    int b;
    int c;
    while (a > 0) {
        b = a % 10;
        c = (c * 10) + b;
        a = a / 10;
    }
    if (z == c) { cout << "This is a palindrome" << endl; }
    else { cout << "This is not a palindrome" < endl; }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in your last cout you forgot a `<` character should be: else{cout<<"This is not a palindrome"<<endl;}

Comment: edit your question

Comment: Just learn to interpret the error message. What have you made of it? (I presume: nothing.)

Comment: I did try to interpet it but I kept looking at the first << of the cout and completely forgot about the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got the above error

The last

```
<endl;
```

Must be

```
<<endl;
```

Be careful reading error messages. They give line number and character position in the line where error occurred.

> I could have sworn I looked at the code 10 times.

If you would format your code perfectly, you would find the error quite quickly. For example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Write a number to check if its palindrome" << endl;
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  int z = a;
  int b;
  int c;
  while (a > 0) {
    b = a % 10;
    c = (c * 10) + b;
    a = a / 10;
  }
  if (z == c) {
    cout << "This is a palindrome" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "This is not a palindrome" < endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

> why it shows me that the number is not a palindrome no matter what I
>   put in it would be useful

You do not initialize `c` with zero before the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I could have sworn I looked at the code 10 times. I guess I need to train myself more to look for those stupid mistakes

Comment: You should not prefix your question title with **(ANSWERED)**. You should mark the answer that helped you.

Comment: Okay, sorry for being trouble.I fixed it. I am new to all of this so sorry if I make mistakes  :/